# Mysql - Get distinct value on one field ordered by another field

Tags: mysql, group-by

Let's assume the given MYSQL table structure

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | group | count |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | cat   |    11 |
|  2 | cat   |    12 |
|  3 | dog   |     4 |
|  4 | dog   |     6 |
|  5 | cow   |    16 |
|  6 | cow   |    12 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

What I want to do is : Take one animal per animal group, ordered by the count field ascending. In the example above, the output should be :

```
|  1 | cat   |    11 |
|  3 | dog   |     4 |
|  6 | cow   |    12 |
```

But it's more complexe than it looks like. What is the most optimized query to get thoses results ? (Of course, making a subquery for each group is not an option)

Answer (score 2):

As per the manual...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT `group`, MIN(count) count FROM my_table GROUP BY `group`) y
    ON y.group = x.group
   AND y.count = x.count;
```

Comment: Thanks for your query, but one problem stay : If animals from the same group has the same count, it will take them all. The query should keep exactly one animal per group.

Comment: @AdamS Which one?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the criteria can be anything, even rand.

Comment: RAND is the toughest criterion to emulate satisfactorily :-(

Comment: True. Well let's say the id then ;)

Answer (score 0):

From `MySQL 8.0+` you could use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `group` ORDER BY `count`) AS rn
     FROM table_name) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=df64d0b00499e0e33ed36bf1f49ed93d)**

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid MySQL goes modern. It will support CTE/windowed functions from version 8 and above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the mysql version I want to target is far above ;)